# Delete a pointer getting AccessViolationException

Tags: c++

I have a class pointer declaration:

```
MyClass* a;
```

In destruction method I have:

```
    if (a)
    {
        delete a;
        a= NULL;
    }
```

I got a problem when delete the pointer a:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

What is the cause of the problem and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Just because is `a` is not `NULL` does not mean it points to a valid object. Is `a` initialised to `NULL` if it never gets assigned a `new MyClass()`? `delete` on a `NULL` pointer is safe so the check for non-null is not necessary.

Comment: more info is needed, can you give the context of the new. PS make sure you never delete `a` in other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current declaration:

```
MyClass* a;
```

`a` gets a random value. If you never give it a valid value later, such as:

```
a = new MyClass();
```

It will point to an unknown place in memory, quite probably not a memory area reserved for your program, and hence the error when you try to delete it.

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to give `a` a value when you declare it:

```
MyClass* a = new MyClass();
```

or, if you cannot give it a value when you declare it (maybe you don't know it yet), assign it to null:

```
MyClass* a = 0;
```

By the way, you can remove the test (`if (a)`) from your code. `delete` is a no-op on a null pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG: 99% of the time (make it 99.9% if you want) this is correct. But sometimes it is not. For instance, if you are implementing a class to manage the pointer (such as a smart pointer). In any case, it seems to me that OP thinks that declaring a pointer automatically sets it to a null value; you can have him use smart pointers, but he will remain with this fundamental mistake. Better have him learn first what's going on and then he can understand why using smart pointers is a superior idea.

Comment: Except such classes trivially ship in the Standard and there is no reason to implement them yourself.

Comment: @DeadMG: Unless you are writing the standard library, for instance. Knowing how pointers work is basic for a C++ programmer. If you know that well enough, you will eventually know why a smart pointer is almost always the right thing. And you will now why it is *almost* always, and how to handle the other cases.

Comment: It's more important to use it than to waste years writing buggy programs with manual memory management errors, and writing the Standard library is such a small niche that it's not relevant on a general-purpose question.

Comment: @Gorpik: I would argue that knowing how pointers works is Advanced for a C++ programmer, since 99.9% will never need to touch it, and it's far simpler than the standard methods.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Call me old school, but I disagree.

Answer (score 2):

unless you have initialized the pointer to something after this:

```
MyClass* a;
```

the pointer `a` will hold some random value. So your test

```
if (a) { }
```

will pass, and you attempt to delete some random memory location.

You can avoid this by initializing the pointer:

```
MyClass* a = 0;
```

Other options are that the object pointed to has been deleted elsewhere and the pointer not set to `0`, or that it points to an object that is allocated on the stack.

As has been pointed out elsewhere, you *could* avoid all this trouble by using a smart pointer as opposed to a bare pointer in the first place. I would suggest having a look at [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: but I declare MyClass* a in header file so if I set the value for it, i have to set it as a static variable?

Comment: @olidev No, it it is a data member, you should set it in the constructor initializer list, which would be in the header or the implementation file.

Answer (score 2):

Use smart pointer to free memory. `delete` in application code is always wrong.

Comment: "delete in application code is always wrong."  Hard lines like this are closed-minded.

Comment: There is not enough context to determine whether delete can be avoided. OP could be trying to implement a smart pointer for all I know.

Comment: @JohnDibling: All places that I can think of where `delete` would be used, It's trivial to use a underlying `unique_ptr`.  If you have `unique_ptr`, you do not need `delete`.

Comment: @John But more often right than wrong. This is a very good guideline. Yes, it may very occasionally incur overhead but this is such a small disadvantage, and carries so overwhelming advantages in general, that the balance tips trivially in favour of following this guideline consistently. And you are wrong, it **does** answer the question since it explicitly solves OP’s problem once and for all.

Comment: @juan I think the post provides enough information to exclude that possibility.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't disagree that it is usually a good guideline.  What I disagree with is 1) The sentiment that OP shouldn't even bother knowing how to use `delete` and `new` (implied by the fact that @DeadMG didn't answer the actual question) 2) It is **always** wrong.  If DeadMG had answered the actual question jbefore getting on the soapbox *and* had used a less-absolute term than "always", I would not have d/v'ed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph probably, but I think it is worth explaining to OP what could be going wrong with their code. This does not preclude suggesting alternatives.

Comment: @John This is Stack Overflow, not a detailed, technical book. Furthermore, we can assume that the OP is fairly new to C++. I believe that general guidelines (yes, that use “always”) do provide the most appropriate advice for the target audience, and that more detailed expositions would confuse more than help. Furthermore, I’m still not convinced that the advice is actually ever wrong. Note the caveat “application code”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  Seems to me that it has always been much closer to a detailed technical book before than to a tutorial for newbs.  Just take a look at the [C++-faq] entries.  They are not written for newbs.  They are deep technical dives, written with an eye for completeness rather than consumability.  Many of the highest-voted questions not in the faq tag are those that focus on minutiae and seek technical elaboration, and the "best" answers are often the ones that quote the Standard.  The SO [C++] tag has always been highly technical -- and much the better for it, if you ask me,

Answer (score 1):

How did you allocate the memory that `a` points to? If you used `new[]` (in order to create an array of `MyClass`), you must deallocate it with `delete[] a;`. If you allocated it with `malloc()` (which is probably a bad idea when working with classes), you must deallocate it with `free()`.

If you allocated the memory with `new`, you have probably made a memory management error somewhere else - for instance, you might already have deallocated `a`, or you have written outside the bounds of some array. Try using Valgrind to debug memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
MyClass* a = NULL;
```

in your declaration. If you never instantiate a, the pointer is pointing to an undefined region of memory. When the containing class destructor executes, it tries to `delete` that random location.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `MyClass* a;` you declare a pointer without allocating any memory. You don't initialize it, and `a` is not necessarily NULL. So when you try to delete it, your test `if (a)` succeeds, but deallocation fails.
You should do `MyClass* a = NULL;` or `MyClass* a(nullptr);` if you can use C++11.
(I assume here you don't use `new` anywhere in this case, since you tell us that you only declare a pointer.)

Comment: @DeadMG of course it's better (in most cases) to use a smart pointer, but OP came with a specific question about deletion of a raw pointer. He didn't understand that simply declare a pointer doesn't set it to null, so now he knows something new.